Gatewayapi routing is not working in spring boot 3.x
we are getting below error. Please provide the fix for resolving this issue.
503 SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE "Unable to find instance for test-authservice"
Technology stack:
JDK 21
Spring cloud gateway
Spring boot 3.x
